# Cannot access swift object's function from objc even adding the @objcMembers tag while running UI testing

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I'm working on UI testing code for iOS app recently,
my UI testing code is using swift, but the project itself has some objective-c code, and I create a singleton object for launch arguments settings, which also written by swift, so I adding the @objcMembers tag to the class.

but while running the UI testing code, it seems not capable to reach the variables and functions, the singleton itself also not exists?
something I missed?

```
import UIKit

#if DEBUG

@objcMembers
class EALaunchArugments: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = EALaunchArugments()

// key for property
static private let UITestingKey = "-UITesting"

var isUITesting: Bool {
    let value = self.getLaunchArgumentValue(key: EALaunchArugments.UITestingKey)
    return Bool(value ?? "") ?? false
}

private func getLaunchArgumentValue(key: String) -> String? {
    let arguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
    let indexOfKey = arguments.firstIndex(of: key)

    guard let index = indexOfKey, index != NSNotFound else {
        return nil
    }

    guard index + 1 >= arguments.count else {
        return nil
    }

    return arguments[index + 1]
}

func setAllLaunchArgumentsSettingsForUITesting() {
// some work

}
}

#endif
```